# Удобно ли программировать на планшетах?

Tags: java, tablet

Возможно, вопрос не по теме, но хотелось бы спросить у опытных пользователей: кто сталкивался с нуждой программировать на планшете и удобно ли это делать на базе андроид?

Слышал, что на андроид ставят компиляторы, и что некоторые люди с комфортом набирают код на планшете, как на пк.

Стоит ли пробовать такой способ или лучше взять недорогой ноутбук? Заинтересован, в основном, в программировании на Java.

Comment: нет / нет / нет / нет

Comment: Не знаю, кому-как конечно, но думаю, что связка ноутбук + Android Studio или Eclipse + тест на реальном устройстве будет гораздо удобнее.

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Есть более-менее подходящие планшеты под Windows на x86 - asus transformer pad и ms surface.

Плюсы:

- доступна для использования любая IDE
- можно найти аналогичные планшеты с повышенным DPI экрана для компенсации малой диагонали экрана

Минус:

- маленькая и неудобная клавиатура(surface крайне низкие клавиши, а transformer неудобное расположение клавиш).

Что же касается Android - попробуйте найти хотя бы одну IDE, сравнимую по возможностям с IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans. Аналогов им для Android в принципе нет и не будет ближайшие наверное лет 5. В плане программирования на Java - эти IDE ощутимо помогают своими встроенными инструментами.

В данном вопросе я склонен согласиться с @zzashpaupat - ноутбук будет намного практичнее.

Comment: "Аналогов им для Android в принципе нет и не будет ближайшие наверное лет 5". Ошибаетесь, аналоги [существуют](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui)

Answer (score 2):

Скажу свое личное мнение: ересь это. 
Все нормальные IDE для Java созданы только для ПК: IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans. 
Я бы на вашем месте взял ноутбук и программировал на нем.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовал я както с AIDE  писать под андроидом написать хоть чтото для андроида. такого сатанизма я не видел даже на хеллоуине. ЗЫ планшеты - для домохозяек, феечек и казуал-геймеров. Ну или для спец задачи, где нужно кликать довольно редко (читалки, командные пульты, кладовщики и проч.). А чтобы написать нечно хорошее, отличающееся от Хэллоу Ворлд, нужно кликать часто, и не по экрану а по клавиатуре. пожалуй единтвенный плюс планшетов -  возможность работать стоя.